What is the cause for the acceleration of Earth?
I've read that spacetime curvature is present wherever initially parallel geodesics converge or diverge, and also that mass causes spacetime to curve. If there is indeed spacetime curvature due to the earth, Why are the geodesics in a space-time graph parellel near the Earth's surface? I used to think that the acceleration of Earth upwards is due to the curvature of space-time. Is it that spacetime is only locally flat and the acceleration is ultimately due to the curvature? What is the actual cause of upward acceleration of earth?
I apologise for the weird wording of the question.

By acceleration upwards, do you refer to the particles in the Earth moving outwards away from their (infalling) geodesics? You might also not want to use such a relative word as “up”.

Yes, thats what I intend to ask. I did not know how to properly word 'up' so I figured you intellegent folks would understand what I mean anyway. Apologies.

"Why are the geodesics in a space-time graph parellel near the Earth's surface?" They're not parallel. They either converge on the world line of the Earth's center of mass, or else they are helices that wind around it. But, if you're judging it by dropping objects a few meters apart and through a few meters of distance, you can be forgiven for thinking that their trajectories are parallel when they actually are converging on a point that is millions of meters distant.

Understood, thank you.

I am not sure which kind of spacetime diagram you are referring to. Maybe that would be helpful.
Firstly, something that can create confusion is mixing up space and space time. For example, the moon's trajectory around the earth might appear curved in space (this is a problematic concept in GR), but the world line of the moon in spacetime is straight i.e., a geodesic (This of course assumes that the moon behaves like a test particle).
While the orbits of satellites at different heights (but in the same plane) can be seen as locally parallel in space (in the sense that the orbits locally look like parallel lines), the world lines in space-time are not parallel at all.
Since spacetime is curved, the notion “parallel lines” is ill-defined because you cannot compare the directions of curves at different spacetime points (compare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_transport)
Concerning your last question, I assume you are asking why objects on the earth are not moving along their geodesics, (which would mean that they accelerate towards the earths core in a Newtonian view). The reason is that the geodesic equation only describes the motion of free-falling objects. If other forces act on a test particle, the world-line is described by
$$m\ \ddot{x}^{\mu} + m\ \Gamma_{\lambda \nu}^{\mu}\ \dot{x}^{\lambda}\ \dot{x}^{\nu} = K^{\mu}$$
where $K^\mu$ is the additional force. E.g., what makes your world line deviate from a geodesic is the (electromagnetic) force that the ground is applying on you. What prevents the earth from collapsing as a whole is the internal pressure. So in summary, the other fundamental forces let matter deviate from geodesic motion.

That was very insightful, thank you.
